# Importing a Dataset into RDLC file Wizard stopped working

Tags: c#, import, dataset, report, rdlc

Weeks ago I created a few (RDLC) reports. To create a Dataset I defined a dummy class and I imported with the procedure, it worked well.

```
public class DataSetCartaIntestata
{
    public string Desc
    public string Immage;
    public string Name;
}
```

I did that to get the result of a query with Anonymous type:

```
public IEnumerable list;
list= b.Results.Where(x=>x.Name="Jack").Select(x=>new{x.Name,x.Image,x.Desc}).ToList();
```

Now it seems that if I'm going to do that again the procedure won't let me add a Dataset.
When I select new Dataset it creates the Datasource but not the Dataset.

Is there anything I got wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Found the answare is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms251784.aspx) the import pocedure import only properties not simple fields of a class even if they are public. so i had to define them.

anyway if I define by hand the Dataset in the RDLC i can access directly fields.

It's easier to make Mistake changing xml plus VS2012 is a bit touchy on the RDLC and crash a lot